# Python regex for a complex string

Tags: python, regex

Below I have a String which i want to split using delimiter spaces such that spaces in double-qouted values are ignored. Example:

```
string = '3e656b8e06c176 el-s3-log-file [24/Dec/2014:11:54:18 +0000] 
202.141.245.38 arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/xyz E27FFBA2CA3D61F3 REST.GET.OBJECT 
logs/2014-12-23-09-25-19-E39257 "GET /el-s36 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 660 660 30 30 
"https://s3-console-us-standard/Console.html?region&locale=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" -'

values = string.split(' ')
```

Above splits double-qouted value as well. `Example: ['"GET', '/el-s36', 'HTTP/1.1"']`

Want a regex that ignores spaces coming inside double qoutes and `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\s` instead of a space to match also the line breaks. That is, it would split the input according to the spaces as well as the line breaks.

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)', string)
['3e656b8e06c176', 'el-s3-log-file', '[24/Dec/2014:11:54:18', '+0000]', '202.141.245.38', 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/xyz', 'E27FFBA2CA3D61F3', 'REST.GET.OBJECT', 'logs/2014-12-23-09-25-19-E39257', '"GET /el-s36 HTTP/1.1"', '200', '-', '660', '660', '30', '30', '"https://s3-console-us-standard/Console.html?region&locale=en"', '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"', '-']
```

**Update:**

This would splits the input string according to the spaces which was not present inside the double quotes or `[]`.

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)(?![^\[\]]*\])', string)
['3e656b8e06c176', 'el-s3-log-file', '[24/Dec/2014:11:54:18 +0000]', '202.141.245.38', 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/xyz', 'E27FFBA2CA3D61F3', 'REST.GET.OBJECT', 'logs/2014-12-23-09-25-19-E39257', '"GET /el-s36 HTTP/1.1"', '200', '-', '660', '660', '30', '30', '"https://s3-console-us-standard/Console.html?region&locale=en"', '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"', '-']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer with one exception though. Value inside [] needs to ignore space slitting too. Example '[24/Dec/2014:11:54:18 +0000]' is to be treated as single value.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('(".*?"|\[.*?\]|[^ ]+)',string)
```

(updated to be the proper amount of greedy)

Comment: Doesnt split: 200 60 30

Comment: Fixed, was being too greedy within the quotes.